# check query row count with php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update

I am very green in PHP. I need to create a small service on server side which will grab data, transform it  and populate it into MySQL database.

Everything is fine so far. I managed to create PHP script which updates existing rows in my database.

I have difficulties with checking If I need to update or add rows. Could you help me?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "almazini";
$password = "3334444";
$dbname = "almazini";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

then I have a loop through my array ... and executing SQL query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE MyTargetTable SET SRate = $sr, BRate = $br WHERE Name='$name' AND SName = '$surname' ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

How can I check if there is a row in MyTargetTable which I should update? If there is no such row - I would like to fire another query to insert new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `UNIQUE` constraint on the MySQL table itself to not allow duplicate values. Run the following from your mysql connection console:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTargetTable
ADD UNIQUE INDEX FullName (Name, SName);
```

Next, use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyTargetTable VALUES (what, ever, values, here)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SRate = :sr, BRate = :br";
```

and then bind the variables `$sr` and `$br` later as shown in [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

Comment: Very elegant solution which does exactly what I need! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should first check from database by passing your parameters in the query and if the count returned is greater than 0 than update, otherwise insert the new row.

Algorithm is like this

```
$count= "SELECT count(*) as count FROM MyTargetTable WHERE Name='$name' AND SName = '$surname'" ;

if(count > 0)
$sql = // Your Update Query
else
$sql = //your insert query
```

Hope this helps